# Forcing a .NET, multithreaded volatile optimization bug

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, volatile

I'm trying to reproduce the bug described in *CLR via C#*.  When the following code is compiled with optimizations the `s_stopWorker` variable is only checked once (and is `false`) so the application never terminates.

```csharp
private static bool s_stopWorker;

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Main: letting worker run for 5 seconds");
    var t = new Thread(Worker);
    t.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    s_stopWorker = true;
    Console.WriteLine("Main: waiting for worker to stop");
    t.Join();
}

private static void Worker(object o)
{
    var x = 0;
    while (!s_stopWorker) x++;
    Console.WriteLine("Worker: stopped when x={0}", x);
}
```

This is indeed what is happening (both on x86 and x64, contrary to the book).

If I put a `Console.Write` in the `while` then suddenly the optimization doesn't happen anymore.

```csharp
private static bool s_stopWorker;

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Main: letting worker run for 5 seconds");
    var t = new Thread(Worker);
    t.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    s_stopWorker = true;
    Console.WriteLine("Main: waiting for worker to stop");
    t.Join();
}

private static void Worker(object o)
{
    var x = 0;
    while (!s_stopWorker)
    {
        Console.Write(string.Empty);  // <-- Added line
        x++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Worker: stopped when x={0}", x);
}
```

Now the bug has vanished and the application exits as if the optimization hadn't happened.

```
Main: letting worker run for 5 seconds
Main: waiting for worker to stop
Worker: stopped when x=130084144
```

Why does the addition of the `Console.Write` fix this bug?

Comment: it's not a bug, it's a feature, your variable should be declared volatile, also with optimisation , and without unchecked you will throw when x will reach maxint

Comment: @Boo the application not doing what it should be doing is a bug.  Yes, the fix for the bug is to use the `volatile` keyword.  That doesn't explain why `Console.Write` should fix the bug though.

Comment: (Aside) I just want to point out that [the use of the `volatile` keyword should be avoided](http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/12/04/sayonara-volatile/). Instead, use [`Volatile.Read()` and `Volatile.Write()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.volatile(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code inside of `Console.Write` could change the value of the static field. It does not but the JIT does not know that. So it must generated code to load the static field each iteration.

You could achieve the same effect by calling an empty method that has the no inlining flag set. This is a black box to the JIT.

The JIT *could* analyze all code that might be called transitively and conclude, that the static field will not change. But this is not implemented in the JIT.

Comment: Is that saying that `Console.Write` uses `volitile`, which is the solution to this bug?

Comment: No, it could contain `s_stopWorker = true;`. This would make the caching optimization invalid.

Comment: @xanatos How could `Console.Write` change the value?

Comment: @BanksySan It could use reflection to access `s_stopWorker` and change it to true, for example.

Comment: @BanksySan Through reflection for example. `typeof(YourClass).GetField("s_stopWorker", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).SetValue(null, true)`

Comment: Or, you could have created a lambda `() => s_stopWorker = true;` and somehow made that lambda available to the `Console` class possibly by setting some global field. This is not the case but it could be. No reflection necessary.

Comment: @xanatos Cheers, wouldn't any of those arguments be true for any method?

Comment: Just tried adding a call to `Math.Pow` in the loop, it doesn't cause the `s_worker` to be reloaded each time.  What's special about `Console.Write`?

Comment: @BanksySan maybe pow is special. It might get inlined or converted to an intrinsic. Maybe the JIT has knowledge about the Math class. Try anything else or even an empty non-inline method.

Comment: @BanksySan `Math.Pow()` is inlined. `Console.WriteLine()` is not. That's the difference. (`Math.Pow()` is attributed as `MethodImplOptions.InternalCall` also)

Comment: @MatthewWatson You're right!  Replacing it with a `Math.Abs()` didn't cause the value to be reloaded.  I don't understand what the inlining does, but that can be the next thing.

Comment: @BanksySan inlining replaces the call with the called code. That way the JIT can see all memory operations and conclude that nothing invalidates that field. The JIT could do the same analysis across methods without inlining but that is not implemented.